# Get days between two Dates

Tags: javascript

```
Function countdays(){


var oneday = 24*60*60*1000;

var sd = $('#sdate').val();// Start date from DOM element type input text(DD/MM/YYYY)

var start_date = new Date(sd);

var ed = $('#edate').val();// End date from DOM element type input text(DD/MM/YYYY)

var end_date = new Date(ed);


var days = Math.floor((start_date.getTime() - end_date.getTime())/(oneday));

alert(days);

}
```

I am trying to run this function, when i put date in format DD/MM/YYYY for start date and end date, JavaScript is taking as MM/DD/YYYY.

Is there any way by which I can keep my date format as DD/MM/YYYY and get difference between start date and end date

Answer (score 1):

Never use `new Date(string)` because it depends on the user's locale.

You should break the date string into year, month and day and then call `new Date(year, month - 1, day)`

Your are right to use `getTime` to find the number of days.

Answer (score 1):

May I make a pitch for [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) when manipulating DateTimes in JavaScript?  Raw Date objects have a lot of corner cases.  If you use MomentJS, you can make use of the [difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) method.

```
var start_date = moment(sd);
var end_date = moment(ed);

var days = end_date.diff(start_date, "days");

console.log(days); // should be the integer you want to test
```

What's extra nice about using MomentJS is that the code is readable when you come back to the logic 3 months from now, and it allows you to adjust for weird things like time zones.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the date format yourself.

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var d = str.split('/')
    return new Date(parseInt(d[2]),parseInt(d[1]) - 1, parseInt(d[0]));
}
function countdays(){

var oneday = 24*60*60*1000;

var start_date = parseDate($('#sdate').val());
var end_date = parseDate($('#edate').val());


var days = Math.floor((start_date.getTime() - end_date.getTime())/(oneday));

alert(days);
}
```

Comment: @ivan Plenty    I tried what did u written on that answer but still it's not working, same it's taking as month first rather than day first

Comment: @user3060271 Wrong answer you commented on :)